# Is there a pythonic way to merge repetitive commands for csv manipulation?

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, repeat

The output works and it does what I need to do but is there a more pythonic way of doing this?
I am basically trying to filter through a csv and find total unique elements for each patient.

I have to write the code in that specific way to make sure that my data is aligning correctly without losing the format. I'm just wondering if there is a more pythonic way of doing this? I would even take resources instead of code. I just want to be efficient. I am still a python newbie and am limited by the fact that I can use only import csv, os, and string.
The reason my rows are starting off at row 5 through 15 is because I don't need anything from columns 1-4 for this part.

my code is below:

```
        diagnosiscounts = csv.reader(self.unique_diagnosis)
        patID = []
        cd1 = []
        cd2 = []
        cd3 = []
        cd4 = []
        cd5 = []
        cd6 = []
        cd7 = []
        cd8 = []
        cd9 = []
        

        test = {}
        diag = {}
        hjj = {}
        for row in diagnosiscounts:
            patID.append(row[0])
            cd1.append(row[5])
            cd2.append(row[6])
            cd3.append(row[7])
            cd4.append(row[8])
            cd5.append(row[9])
            cd6.append(row[10])
            cd7.append(row[11])
            cd8.append(row[12])
            cd9.append(row[13])
            
        
        dg1 = tuple(zip(patID,cd1))
        dg2 = tuple(zip(patID,cd2))
        dg3 = tuple(zip(patID,cd3))
        dg4 = tuple(zip(patID,cd4))
        dg5 = tuple(zip(patID,cd5))
        dg6 = tuple(zip(patID,cd6))
        dg7 = tuple(zip(patID,cd7))
        dg8 = tuple(zip(patID,cd8))
        dg9 = tuple(zip(patID,cd9))
        

        for k, v in dg1:
            test.setdefault(k,[]).append(v)
        for k, v in dg2:
            test.setdefault(k,[]).append(v)
        for k, v in dg3:
            test.setdefault(k,[]).append(v)
        for k, v in dg4:
            test.setdefault(k,[]).append(v)
        for k, v in dg5:
            test.setdefault(k,[]).append(v)
        for k, v in dg6:
            test.setdefault(k,[]).append(v)
        for k, v in dg7:
            test.setdefault(k,[]).append(v)
        for k, v in dg8:
            test.setdefault(k,[]).append(v)
        for k, v in dg9:
            test.setdefault(k,[]).append(v)
        
        
        for k, v in test.items():
            tp = []
            for i in v:
                if i != '':
                    tp.append(i)
            diag[k] = set(tp)
        
        for k,v in diag.items():
            hjj[k] = len(v)

        print(hjj)
```

my csv file is structure the following way:

```
Patient_ID      ICD9_DGNS_CD_1  ICD9_DGNS_CD_2  ICD9_DGNS_CD_3  ICD9_DGNS_CD_4  ICD9_DGNS_CD_5 ICD9_DGNS_CD_6   ICD9_DGNS_CD_7  ICD9_DGNS_CD_8  ICD9_DGNS_CD_9  ICD9_DGNS_CD_10
00013D2EFD8E45D1    5.42192E+14 4824842417          V5841                                   
00016F745862898F    5.42272E+14 2963419753         2963419753   V5832              V5861    2724    3182    V5869   42731               
00016F745862898F    5.42282E+14 5737807753         5737807753   9594               E9174    4019                            
0001FDD721E223DC    5.42642E+14 1233847710          78943          V5866           V1272                            
00024B3D2352D2D0    5.42242E+14 9688809345          6009                                    
00024B3D2352D2D0    5.42442E+14 4199631965          6115                                    
00024B3D2352D2D0    5.42422E+14 1449018601          2723                                    
00024B3D2352D2D0    5.42372E+14 5972737463          V821                                    
0002F28CE057345B    5.42052E+14                                                                                546645             3255             4566                     45974
0002F28CE057345B    5.42162E+14 7985077191          7902                                    
0002F28CE057345B    5.42192E+14 420175516           7232                                    
0002F28CE057345B    5.42342E+14 7535793863          25012          V5867                                
0002F28CE057345B    5.42472E+14 6022067668          59781                                   
0002F28CE057345B    5.42892E+14                     3482            3569    3320
```

it's just not good code structure to me and I would like to make it nicer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make a list of the objects you want to manipulate, and then iterate through *that* list and do the operation. Such as:

```py
cd_list = [list() for _ in range(10)]
indices = [0, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
test = {}
diag = {}
hjj = {}
for row in diagnosiscounts:
    for index, cd_obj in zip(indices, cd_list):
        cd_obj.append(row[index])

dg_list = list(map(lambda cd_obj: tuple(patID, cd_obj), cd_list))
for dg_obj in dg_list:
    for k, v in dg_obj:
        test.setdefault(k, []).append(v)
```

Without having the objects to directly test, this *should* work, but I cannot be certain.

*Note: as a general rule, if you find yourself repeating an action more than once or twice, your **first** instinct should be to consider how you could use looping to accomplish it more efficiently.*

Comment: ! thank you for helping me! I am really working on for loops and have a little trouble with them. Unfortunately, I can't use lambda in my functions either.

Comment: Is there a specific issue with `lambda` I can help you with? @VS

Comment: I am not able to use lambda. It's not a problem with lambda, for the assignment I just am not able to use lambda at all.

Comment: Well any `lambda` function can be replaced by a named function,so that shouldn't be a big deal - let me know if you have any problems!

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is a more elegant way to group combinations.

Perhaps something or a combination like:

```
from collections import defaultdict

diagnosiscounts = [
    ('00013D2EFD8E45D1', '5.42192E+14', '4824842417'),
    ('00016F745862898F', '5.42272E+14', '2963419753'),
]

data = defaultdict(list)
data_by_patient = {}
for row in diagnosiscounts:
    for i, c in enumerate(('Patient_ID', 'ICD9_DGNS_CD_1', 'ICD9_DGNS_CD_2')):
        data[c].append(row[i])
        data_by_patient[row[0]] = row[1:]
```

Comment: Add more columns under enumerate as required.